# How do I check if a List contains an object of a certain type? C#

Tags: c#, xna

I have a list (called `Within`), and it contains objects of type `GameObject`.
`GameObject` is a parent class to many others, including `Dog` and `Ball`. I want to make a method that returns true if Within contains any object of type `Ball`, but I don't know how to do this.

I've tried using `Count<>`, `Any<>`, `Find<>` and a few other methods provided within C#, but I couldn't get them to work.

```
public bool DetectBall(List<GameObject> Within)
{
    //if Within contains any object of type ball:
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
if (within.OfType<Ball>().Any())
```

The generic parameter of all LINQ methods except `Cast<T>()` and `OfType<T>()` is used to allow the method call to compile and must be compatible with the type of the list (or for a covariant cast).  They cannot be used to filter by type.

Answer (score 12):

in non-linq if you're interested

```
public bool DetectBall(List<GameObject> Within)
{
    foreach(GameObject go in Within)
    {
        if(go is Ball) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```