# C# How to check if a List of interface objects contains a certain object?

Tags: c#, list, object

I have the interface Packageable which looks like this:

```
public interface Packageable
{
    double GetPrice(double modifier);
}
```

I then have 4 classes, all inheriting from Packageable, with the only difference being the price. These are SwimmingPool, Gym, Dancing and Billiards and they look like this:

```
class Billiards : Packageable
{
    public double GetPrice(double modifier)
    {
        double price = 38;
        switch (modifier)
        {
            case 2:
                modifier = 0.7;
                break;
            case 3:
                modifier = 0.5;
                break;
            case 4:
                modifier = 0.35;
                break;
        }
        return price * modifier;
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a main class (of which the relevant elements) looks like this:

```
public class People
{
    public List<Packageable> Packages = new List<Packageable>();
    public List<Packageable> ReturnPackages()
    {
        return Packages;
    }
}
```

In my main form I want to check whether the list Packages contains one of the objects. This is what I attempted:

```
if (people[lbMain.SelectedIndex].ReturnPackages().Contains(SwimmingPool)) {}
```

However, as SwimmingPool is a type and not an object, Visual Studio throws an error. I tried to mend this by creating an object of each class, however that also did not work:

```
SwimmingPool swimmingpool = new SwimmingPool();
if (people[lbMain.SelectedIndex].ReturnPackages().Contains(swimmingpool)) {}
```

This code runs, but never returns a true. How do I do this properly?

Comment: Something like `ReturnPackages().OfType<SwimmingPool>().Any()`?

Comment: Same question asked here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216881/how-do-i-check-if-a-list-contains-an-object-of-a-certain-type-c-sharp

Comment: @vc74 This works! Care to make a full reply to explain in a bit more detail how it works? That way I can also choose your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [OfType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8) extension method that returns the elements from a collection inheriting from a specific base class or implementing a specific interface.

Combined with the [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) extension method (the one that doesn't take a predicate in parameter) which returns true if a collection contains at least one element, you'll get what you want.

You can also use the [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) override that takes a predicate in parameter as suggested by @Mureinik.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Any` with a lambda expression that checks the type:

```cs
if (people[lbMain.SelectedIndex].ReturnPackages()
                                .Any(p => p.GetType() == typeof(SwimmingPool))) 
{
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: simplified version : 

if (people[lbMain.SelectedIndex].ReturnPackages().OfType<Billiards>().Any())
  {}